# using a TIdSMTP component to send mails to a server with TLS/SSL configuration

Tags: email, openssl, delphi-7, indy10

I need to send mails using Delphi7 and the Indy10 component TIdSMTP; the mail must sent to the server of the Italian tax office.

I used a simple MAPI component to send emails, but now it is necessary to use the Indy components, but I don't know them.

I try to create a program as this:

```
procedure TForm1.BtCreateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  DATA : TIdMessage;
  SMTP : TIdSMTP;
  SSL : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  try
    SMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
    DATA := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    SSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    SSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;     // or sslmUnassigned ?
    SSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    SSL.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
    DATA.From.Address := eUser.Text;       // 'my.name@pec.it'
    DATA.Recipients.EMailAddresses := eDest.Text; // 'recipient@pec.it'
    DATA.Subject := eOggetto.Text;         // 'dispatch of test'
    DATA.Body.Text := eCorpo.Lines.Text;   // ' Isend a mail from "pec" client to "ord" server)
    if (eAlleg.Text <> '') and FileExists(eAlleg.Text) then
       TIdAttachmentFile.Create(DATA.MessageParts, eAlleg.Text); 
    SMTP.IOHandler := SSL;
    SMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
    SMTP.Host := eHost.Text;               // 'imaps.pec.aruba.it';
    SMTP.Port := StrToInt(ePorta.Text);    // 993 ;
    SMTP.Username := eUser.Text;           // 'my.name@pec.it'
    SMTP.Password := ePassw.Text;          // 'my_password_123'
    // SMTP.SASLMechanisms;                // no
    try
      try
        SMTP.Connect;
        SMTP.Send(DATA);
      except
        on E:Exception do
           ShowMessage('Non posso spedire E-Mail: ' + E.Message);
      end;
    finally
      if SMTP.Connected then SMTP.Disconnect;
    end;
  except
    on E : Exception do
    ShowMessage('Errore durante la spedizione del file: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

I've inserted the "libeay32.dll" and the "ssleay32.dll" in the \Windows\System32 directory (rel: openssl 1.0.2q).

After the click, it seems the mail is sent, the circle appear (screen.Hourglass) but any following action (loop?). No error message.

I believe this is a problem of handshake, some property not communicated by the client. The TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL'setup is incomplete?

I admit that the Indy documentation is too difficult and time-consuming for me, I've not got the correct knowledge to understand the use of the various properties.

Is someone able to point out to me why the program doesn't work?

Comment: DO NOT put the OpenSSL DLLs in the Windows system folder, they belong in your app's own folder instead (or any other folder of your choosing, if you call `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` at app startup). As for the code, I don't see anything wrong with it, but nothing in it touches the `Screen.Cursor` so it shouldn't be changing. However, are you really trying to connect to `imaps.pec.aruba.it:993` as your code's comments suggest? That is not an SMTP server, that is an IMAP server. You need to use `TIdIMAP4` instead for IMAP.

Comment: Good morning. I divide the answer into two parts. (.1.) I've moved the two Dlls into a common directory ('C:\Work') and I've included in the OnCreate event of the Form "IdOpenSSLSetLibPath('c:\Work');". But a message "Could not load SSL library" appear and process stops. The "IsSSLOpenSSLHeaders" unit is in the Uses clause. If I move the two Dlls in the same directory of the app, this message don't appear. Where is the mistake?

Comment: (.2.) I've changed the IdSMTP component with the IdIMAP4 component, leaving the other values unchanged. Only the procedure "Send(IdMsg)" change to "Send(Idmsg,False)": The IdIMAP4.Host contains "imaps.pec.aruba.it" but the behaviour is the same: at the click, the app starts, no error occur, the system cursor change in circle (I don't insert any change to Screen.Cursor property, is Windows that changes it).

Comment: After the "could not load" error occurs, call the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.WhichFailedToLoad()` function to find out why. As for `TIdIMAP`, you can't send emails with IMAP, you need SMTP. My earlier point was that if you were connecting to a non-SMTP server to begin with, that would explain why `TIdSMTP` wasn't working correctly for you. The correct SMTP server is `smtps.pec.aruba.it:465` (per [Access your Ingpec.eu (Aruba PEC) Account from an Email Program](https://getmailspring.com/setup/access-ingpec-eu-via-imap-smtp)). Use `UseTLs=utUseImplicitTLS` on port 465.

Comment: YEAHHHH!!!!   Great, Remy, the sender functions very well *_*!!!! Thanks thousand! I was desperate... I'd love to buy a cup of coffee... here in Italy is a good practice ^-^ A last question: how does it make to know that the delivery has happened? I've seen the event OnStatus: in a silent sent (in background, via programs), activating this function can I receive a grant of delivery? How? Thanks again

Comment: if `TIdSMTP.Send()` does not throw an exception, the email was accepted by the SMTP server you are connected to. Move on. But that is no guarantee that the email will actually arrive at the specified recipient(s). If delivery fails on-route after SMTP accepts it, an error message will be sent to the email address you are sending from. You can also request a read/delivery receipt in the email itself, but that is no guarantee the recipient(s) will reply. Either way, you would have to monitor the sender's mailbox with POP3 or IMAP for such notifications.

Comment: If I've whell understand, if the flow remain in the block "try..except", this grants ALSO that no exceptions are raised, and not that the mail has been SENT to recipient: here I can insert a message "mail sent..."; else if the flow jumps to the block "except..end", the user receive the message raised by the E.Exception class. is this right?  With an Imap component, later, the program must download the mails from the mailbox and try to interpret the various messages received to look to such notifications type "mail delivery notification"; is this the work?

Comment: essentially, yes

Comment: Good morning, I use this topic, because I believe this is the same matter. When I send a mail (IdSMTP.Send;) the time is of some second. But to send more than one mail (with a different enclosure) to the same IdMessage.Recipients.EmailAddresses (10-20-30...), the time could become enormous!!! Is it necessary to recall the same entire routine (Create-Add-Send-Disconnect) every time? or is possible to re-use a part of the routine (new IdAttachmentFile.Create, new message, new Send), with a unique Connect and a unique Disconnect (using a for cycle to find the single file to attach) ? And how?

Comment: yes, you can send more than 1 email per connection (within the anti-spamming limitations of the SMTP server, of course), reusing/altering the `TIdMessage` as needed.

Comment: Ok, but with one Connect and one Disconnect? changing only the content of coponent IdMessage (Clear/Add)?

Comment: Yes, you can call `Send()` multiple times within a single set of `Connect()`/`Disconnect()` calls.

Comment: Thanks, Remy, and wishes of good Native.

Answer (score 0):

*Substitutions:*

SSL.SSLOptions.Method: = sslvTLSv1;
**with**
SSL.SSLOptions.Method: = sslvTLSv1_2;

SMTP.UseTLS: = utUseExplicitTLS;
**with**
SMTP.UseTLS: = utUseImplicitTLS;

**Then use:**
SMTP.Host: = 'smtps.pec.aruba.it';
SMTP.Port: = 465;

It is then necessary to use the openssl-1.0.2q-i386-win32 library
libeay32.dll
ssleay32.dll

Insert in FormCreate

IdOpenSSLSetLibPath (path of the two libraries: it is better to insert them where the program is);

For the above method enter in Uses: IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders

Tried and with Aruba PEC it works.